# Failed to get recommend Cuboid

Tags: cube, kylin

when I click on model--planner--recommend,an error occurred.
"Failed to get recommend Cuboid;Check whether you have enabled System Cube."

Comment: After building system cube,this problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

After buildding system cube,the problem was solved.